# Query doesn't work with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a query based on some field in my database.
I'm trying to select a cell with a string CONTAIN a keyword.
It's the `LIKE` code that do not work.
Error code follows:

Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

**PHP**

```
$query = " 
            SELECT 1 
            FROM phpexcel
            WHERE objekt_nr = :objekt_nr && element_nr = :element_nr && element_scanned_where LIKE '%:element_scanned_where%'"; 

        $query_params = array(
            ':objekt_nr' => $ean_objekt_nr,
            ':element_nr' => $ean_element_nr,
            ':element_scanned_where' => $element_scanned_where
            );
```

Comment: @Buisson why would you?

Comment: fyi: you do not need quotations on those named placeholders, and of course don't forget to load in the the prepare function and execute it.

Comment: @Buisson && Works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = " 
            SELECT 1 
            FROM phpexcel
            WHERE objekt_nr = :objekt_nr && element_nr = :element_nr && element_scanned_where LIKE :element_scanned_where"; 

        $query_params = array(
            ':objekt_nr' => $ean_objekt_nr,
            ':element_nr' => $ean_element_nr,
            ':element_scanned_where' => '%'.$element_scanned_where.'%'
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$query = " 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM phpexcel
        WHERE objekt_nr = :objekt_nr AND element_nr = :element_nr AND element_scanned_where LIKE %:element_scanned_where%"; 

    $query_params = array(
        ':objekt_nr' => $ean_objekt_nr,
        ':element_nr' => $ean_element_nr,
        ':element_scanned_where' => $element_scanned_where
        );
```

Comment: For readability's sake I'd suggest changing the `and`s to `AND`s, but other than that, all good.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work! S.Pols example does. And i can use && whitout any problems.